# Suddenly stopped receiving otps from aws-cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using aws cognito with aws amplify, it was working fine and i was receiving otps at the time of signup and resend otp but it now stopped suddenly the apis are working fine (like an unconfirmed user gets created at the time of signup and resendSignup api also responds successfully) but i am not receiving any otps, what could be the possible reasons? or how do i check where the problem lies.

```
Ionic V1

aws-amplify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can send SMS worth 1.00 USD only. You will have to request a limit increase in your SMS spends.

> The default spend limit per account (if not specified) is 1.00 USD per month. If you want to raise the limit, submit an SNS Limit Increase case in the AWS Support Center. For New limit value, enter your desired monthly spend limit. In the Use Case Description field, explain that you're requesting an SMS monthly spend limit increase.

Check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Since suddeenly, the messages have completely stopped coming so you might have reached the SNS SMS spend limit for your account. By default it is 1 USD for a AWS account in a AWS region. You should get your limit increased.

But in future if you want to prevent this i.e. if you want to get notified earlier before you reach the actual SMS Spend Limit for your account so that limit can be increased before hand. In this way you would not face SMS delivery issues due to limit being reached. You can create a CloudWatch Alarm on your SMSMonthToDateSpentUSD metric.

Please have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-HdLf_lizI

Answer (score 1):

This might be happened due to 2 reasons mainly.

1. Monthly SMS limit. [Read more Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-sms-text-message.html)
2. New TRAI policy (Only applicable in INDIA).